# php tree sitemap algorithm with no rucursion

Tags: php, algorithm, sitemap

I want to make a sitemap generator and the generated sitemap must be be like a tree.Can someone point me to an algorithm that does this? Or does anyone know the algorithm?
The structure of the sitemap should look like something like this :

[image]

I was thinking to use arrays to do this but i can't think of an algorithm to get all links from the website and build the arrays.

Comment: Where and in what structure do you get your site info (the links or categories) from?

Comment: Breadth first search of the hyper-link graph of your site should be able to do this, as long as you also keep track of your current depth.

Comment: "with no recursion" ... Why are you intentionally looking for bad answers ?

Comment: From the links,i want to crawl the website and look for all links and in the process to organize them like in the image above

Comment: If it's just links on pages, how do you intend to determine which "level" they're at?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with

```
<?php
$links = array('bla.com/bla1/bla2', 'bla.com/bla1', 'bla.com/bla1/bla3', 'bla.com', 'bla.com/blabla/bla1/bla4', 'bla.com/blabla/otherbla/onemorebla');
$links = array_fill_keys($links, 0);
foreach($links as $key => $value){
    $levelsNumber = count(explode('/', $key));
    $links[$key] = $levelsNumber;
}
$output = array();
$maxLevel = 1;
foreach ($links as $link => $levels){
    if ($levels > $maxLevel) $maxLevel = $levels;
}
for($level = 1; $level <= $maxLevel; $level++){
    foreach ($links as $link => $levels){
        $parts = explode('/', $link);
        if (count($parts) >= $level){
            $levelExists = false;

            if (!$levelExists){
                $keysString = '';
                for ($j = 0; $j < $level; $j++){
                    $keysString .= "['".$parts[$j]."']";
                }
                eval('$output'.$keysString.'= NULL;');
                $levelExists = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($output);
?>
```

running it gives

```
Array
(
    [bla.com] => Array
        (
            [bla1] => Array
                (
                    [bla2] => 
                    [bla3] => 
                )
            [blabla] => Array
                (
                    [bla1] => Array
                        (
                            [bla4] => 
                        )

                    [otherbla] => Array
                        (
                            [onemorebla] => 
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I think if you play with it you might get what you've expected.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I made a simple crawler that gets all the links from the website, i use your idea to organize the links and the build an unordered list in html.